# How do you save the contents of a pc game cd on a Mac so that you can run the game later without the cd?

Tags: mac, gaming, cd

Assuming you have a usb cd drive

Comment: You probably don't. They are usually copy-protected. Even if not, many require the actual CD to be present for the game to run, even if the game content is already on the hard drive.

Comment: If this is perceived as a question about hacking copy protection, it would be off-topic.  Otherwise, procedures for any and all game CDs would be too broad, and even more-so if you add the complication of the apparently implied Windows-based games.  To reopen this, you would need to narrow this to the specific game, clarify its platform, provide details of your hardware and OS version, clarify the copy protection issue, etc. (as a minimum).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Mac game on optical disc, you can use Disk Utility to make a disk image (.dmg file) of it. Later you can double-click on that .dmg in the Finder and it will mount it as a virtual disc.